# trying to pass multiple lines, one by one (each line has 3 items separated by a space) fed into a already written script

Tags: shell-script

I have a script that asks 3 questions one by one.
I need a way to run this script in bulk without re-writing it.
The script, when run, looks like this:

```
./test.pl
question a   and I answer with item1
question b   and I answer with item2
question c   and I answer with item3
```

then it runs the script with the 3 fields filled.

Now, I have the file to run; each line has the 3 fields.
I need the script to read each line, and for each line run the 3 items in that line one by one then go on to the next line.

The file is space delimited.
The file looks like this

```
item1 item2 item3

item1 item2 item3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cat file.txt | while read L ; do
    L=($L)
    ./test.pl << EOF
    ${L[0]}
    ${L[1]}
    ${L[2]}
    EOF
done
```

Comment: the OEF at the end it wasn't happy with the space.
I removed the spaces before it.. now its telling me i need a newer version of perl ( i'm running 5.8.4 ).  thinking the syntax is different.

Answer (score 0):

If your shell supports arrays, then one to do it would be to read the space-separated items from each line into an array using a shell loop, and then print them with newlines to the standard input of your program. For example, given an interactive test script (this will be replaced by your `test.pl`)

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Item 1: " item1
read -p "Item 2: " item2
read -p "Item 3: " item3

printf "Items: %s, %s, %s\n" "$item1" "$item2" "$item3"
```

with an answers file

```
$ cat answers
egg sausage bacon
egg bacon spam
spam spam spam
```

then using `bash`

```
while read -r -a items; do printf '%s\n' "${items[@]}" | ./test.sh; done < answers
Items: egg, sausage, bacon
Items: egg, bacon, spam
Items: spam, spam, spam
```

(the trick here is that `printf` reuses the single `%s\n` format until the argument list is exhausted, so we don't need to specify the number of items explicitly). The nice thing is that it can be generalized to other delimiters simply by changing `while read ...` to (for example) `while IFS=, read ...`

In your case, since you have whitespace-separated entries in your file, I don't see a reason to prevent the shell from applying split+glob, so you could avoid the arrays and just read whole lines and pass them *un*quoted to `printf`:

```
while read -r line; do printf '%s\n' $line | ./test.sh; done < answers
Items: egg, sausage, bacon
Items: egg, bacon, spam
Items: spam, spam, spam
```